# Change URL on private site collection Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection, url, domain

My task is to change URL of internal site collection in SharePoint Online. 
The situation is such: it was configured with one domain (DomainA), and now all site collections are:

```
http://domainA.sharepoint.com
http://domainA.sharepoint.com/search
http://domainA-my.sharepoint.com
```

But now the client desided to use different domain. New domain is added and configured in Office365 - DomainB.

Now it is not possible to simple change the url of created site collection.
But client wants to have addresses like `http://domainB.sharepoint.com` .

The site collections are empty for now and never used. Is it possible to delete all site collections starts with `domainA` and create a new ones with `domainB`?

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing tenant URL for SharePoint Online is not possible (not right now at least).

Only way to change change the URL of the private site collection (as in your case), is to cancel the old current Office 365 subscription and start with a new one.

You'd have to look into ways to migrate content from domainA to domainB perhaps using some 3rd party migratio tool. Office 365 support hasn't been able to help with neither of these. I do recommend opening a support case for this, or at least sending feedback to Microsoft to let them know there would be need for this.

Comment: you mean we need to buy subscription with DomainB? There is no content in those site coleecion, so nothing to migrate.

Comment: Extended my answer above, so you need to buy subscription on the domainB, after you can cancel subscription on domainA (unless you want to keep that of course).

Comment: Thanks, now it is more clear. I also thought about new subscription. Have a meeting today, hope they will deside what way too. Thanks again!