# SharePoint online office 365 - Change the site url

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We have SharePoint sites that start with https://abc.sharepoint.com/. How do I change it to be https://xyz.sharepoint.com/?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question:  Please see this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145585/change-url-on-private-site-collection-office-365/145586#145586

Answer (score 3):

The changing of SharePoint online domain is not possible as per Microsoft articles. All the apps and email accounts in your tenant map to the same domain.

It requires to create a new tenant and move all your accounts and data to the new tenant.

Below article link points the complete details about this question.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Can-t-rename-a-SharePoint-team-site-576325ad-8c40-4fe8-8a63-68c3b7d536cf?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Comment: Thank you, Venkat. The client has already licenses and everything and they are currently using the Sharepoint online. Will they have to buy new licenses for new tenant? Are there any detailed steps available for 'create a new tenant and move all your accounts and data to the new tenant.'?

Comment: You can create a service ticket from your current Office 365 admin center. They will assist you in a better way in transferring your licenses.